# how to use vscode restructuredtext extension ( lextudio.restructuredtext) with myst-parser on markdown file?

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown, python-sphinx, myst

I have a project configured to use Sphinx and the Myst-parser to build my documentation.
The build is fine and everything works (my `conf.py` in sphinx is OK).

Now, I use VSCode as an editor and I would like to have a "live preview" in vscode for my "myst-flavored" markdown files.
This means the preview should be the result of a sphinx build of my myst-markdown files.

In vscode I've found the following extensions:

- lextudio.restructuredtext  which offers a live preview *for rst files* and use Sphinx under the hood. Moreover, it should use my own `conf.py` file, so I think it could use the myst-parser as well.
- MyST-Markdown (executablebookproject.myst-highlight) which offers syntax highlighting and directive autocomplete for "myst-flavored" markdown

But I could not find how to "execute" the live preview of restructuredtext  extension on my myst-markdown files.

When I open a markdown file, I can only launch the "markdown preview", for standard markdown, but I cannot execute the restructuredtext preview (via the sphinx build).

**How to use restructuredtext extension on myst-markdown files?**

N.B: I already have the sphinx-autobuild server settup and working (the "dev" server), but find it not handy to preview in the browser instead of vscode directly. Moreover I wanted the preview only of the file being written...

Comment: I don't think anything does what you want. `conf.py` is used exclusively by Sphinx, whereas almost all `.rst` preview apps do not use `conf.py` and use other tools to render the HTML.

Comment: @StevePiercy  the restructuredtext extension seems to use [Sphinx and the `conf.py` file](https://docs.restructuredtext.net/articles/configuration.html#conf-py-path) ,  so I thought if my build works with the sphinx-autobuild server with myst-parser for markdown file, it should work in this extension.

However, I cannot even init/launch the preview of the extension, since i have a .md file and not a .rst file....

Comment: Don't assume the extension does that. Verify it. I have never seen a server that does that. I have only seen preview servers render simple reST without cross-references between documents or only docutils directives.

Comment: MyST is not supported by this VS Code extension. It might be supported, however, if one day esbonio language implements MyST support.